# How to return json response?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Fm01Det(Fm01Det GroupDet)
{
if (sSubMode == "up")
{
//update query
  OdbcCommand up_cmd = new OdbcCommand(sSQL, con);
try
{
  up_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception)
{
  return Json("ERR");
}
finally
{
  con.Close();
}
  return Json("OK");
}
}
  return View(GroupDet);
}
```

The top is my controller . After i press update will trigger value sSubMode == "up"

then update query run ... Then check error return Json

```js
$("#update").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/path",
    success: function(response) {
      if (response == "OK") {
        swal("updated.", {
          icon: "success",
          timer: 1000,
          showCancelButton: false,
          showConfirmButton: false,
          buttons: false,
        }).then(function() {
          window.location = "/path";
        });
      } else {
        swal("Update Fail!", {
          icon: "error",
          timer: 1000,
          showCancelButton: false,
          showConfirmButton: false,
          buttons: false,
        }).then(function() {
          window.location = "/path";
        });
      }
    },
  });
});
```

After that run ajax About.

The problem im having is after i press update ...

return me "OK" with blank page but the swal and window.location not running

Please help me . Thank

Comment: In my opinion, you should use the dev debug tool in the browser to find the root cause, then try to find the answer.

Comment: If you're just returning the word Ok, that is simple plain text. You don't need JSON for that